# HTML form / submit button. How to validate inputs and prevent submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to use a submit button because it checks my form input attributes.

My inputs are all numerical and have attributes of min / max / required all given by jQuery:

```
<form id="form1">
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" /> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </form>
<button form="form1">check inputs</button>
```

And the validation attributes are assigned with jQuery (min: 1, max: 9, required)

```
  $('input').attr({
    min: 1,
    max: 9,
  }).prop('required', true);
```

I have jQuery set up to extract the numerical values from the inputs and put them into an array, but if I use this button, it attempts to 'submit' the form which I don't want. But if I add event.preventDefault() the submit button no longer checks for the min/max/required values.

Essentially all I want my button to do is to check the validation requirements, and trigger the jQuery click event.

EDIT / CLARIFICATION:

I want 3 things:
1. prevent the form from submitting. No POST 
2. Validate / make sure each input has a valid value
3. trigger a jQuery click event 
( $('button').on('click', function(){ do something...  });

Answer (score 3):

Just call `jquery.validate()` and if it fails, invoke `e.preventDefault()`

```
$("button").click(function(e)
     {
        if(!jquery.validate())
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o5y9959b/8/

Comment: I want to always prevent the submit, otherwise the solution seems to be good in the fiddle. However, I'm getting the error: 'jquery is not defined' in my console.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kingcharles/LEZ4r/824/    
this is a fiddle of my actual code, I can't seem to get the form validation to work

Comment: I can trigger an alert on button click. where are seeing the error ? http://jsfiddle.net/LEZ4r/825/

Comment: you have to put e.preventDefaut() inside the validation. Here's the working code : http://jsfiddle.net/LEZ4r/826/

Comment: Thank you, that works better, however the main objective I have from my question is I want the validation to work (which it does), but I don't want the form to submit. If you use the fiddle you sent me, and fill in each cell with a valid value, it will submit and the form will clear. I don't want any POST requests, I just want the button to check the validation and trigger a click event

Comment: in that case, just move e.preventDefault() at the end , http://jsfiddle.net/LEZ4r/827/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94373/discussion-between-jmancherje-and-dinomyte).

Comment: The network at my work just crashed. Once it's up we can catch up.

Answer (score 0):

put this one instead:

```
<form id="form1" >
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required/> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="submit">check inputs</button>
  </form>
```

you don't need to use jquery for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what goes wrong in your case but i explained it again so you can find something that you might find useful.

```
<form id="form1" >
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required /> </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="9" required/> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<button type="submit" class="onlycheck" form="form1">check inputs</button>
<button type="submit" form="form1">Submits form</button>



$("#form1").on('submit',function(e){
     if( $(e.target).hasClass('onlycheck') ){
         /* 
          some extra validation code here if you want 
          e.x : var valid = true;
          $(this).find('input[type=number]').each(function(i,el){
             if( $(el).val() > $(el).attr("max") ||  $(el).val() < $(el).attr("min")){ //notice that is not performant declare first $(el)
                  valid = false;
                  return false; //break the cicle 
             }
         });
         */
         return false;
     }
});
```